# Is $n+1<n^{\frac{n-6}{n-7}}$ equivalent to $\frac{n-6}{n-7}\gt\log_{n}{(n+1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

When I have inequality for $n\in\mathbb{N}\wedge n\ge11$ such as: $n+1<n^{\frac{n-6}{n-7}}$.

Can I turn it into a logarithmic inequality: $\;\frac{n-6}{n-7} \gt \log_{n}{(n+1)}$ ?
Will it give me a proper answer and if yes, why?

Comment: Careful there, $\,\log_n(n+1) \ne \log_n (n) + \log_n(1)\,$. Also, recheck the direction of the inequality.

Comment: The last term in your title would be understood to mean $(\log_n n) +1$.  If you mean $\log_n(n+1),$ please use parentheses.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not checked whether your inequality holds. But regardless, after applying the logarithm the result will be the same. This is because the logarithmic function of base $b > 1$ is increasing everywhere. On the contrary, if it is to be of base $b < 1$, it will be always decreasing so you would have to turn around the inequality sign.

Comment: "*after applying the logarithm the result will be the same.*" $\;-\;$ Might be worth pointing out that the OP reversed the inequality, instead of keeping it the same, so that's the first thing they need to correct.

Comment: So how would you actually solve $\frac{n-6}{n-7} \gt \log_{n}{(n+1)}$ or $n+1<n^{\frac{n-6}{n-7}}$?